# Can it be possible to typecast address of a buffer created in python c_ulonglong?

Tags: python, c++, buffer, ctypes

```
class Test(Structure):
{
  _pack_ = 1
  _fields_ = ["Buffer", c_uint64]
}
```

I want to create a buffer in python and send address of buffer to `c_uint64`

```
a = create_string_buffer('0xaa' * 512)
```

How to send address of a to `c_uint64`?

Comment: `c_uint64(addressof(a))`